# How to delete specific pattern form each line

Tags: python

i need to remove any `#number` form each line like this example

```
   1.jpg#0     One 
   2.jpg#1     Two
   3.jpg#2     Three 
   4.jpg#3     Four 
   5.jpg#4     Five
```

to be like this

```
   1.jpg     One 
   2.jpg     Two
   3.jpg     Three 
   4.jpg     Four 
   5.jpg     Five
```

i tried to use one but its done for one line

```
import os

inputFile = open("input.txt", "r") 
exportFile = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in inputFile:
   new_line = line.replace("#0", '  ')
   exportFile.write(new_line) 

inputFile.close()
exportFile.close()
```

Comment: You are only replace `"#0"` with a blank. You want to loop over all digits.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for this.(I am not too familiar with it so cannot post an exact answer, but I know that it will help you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> with open("a1.txt", "r") as inputFile, open("output.txt", "w") as exportFile: 
...     for line in inputFile:
...         exportFile.write(re.sub('#\d+', '', line))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to match the pattern:

```
import re

for line in inputFile:
   # \d{1,3} -> matches a number between one and three digits
   # \d+ -> matches any number of digits
   new_line = re.sub(r'#\d{1,3}', '', line)
   exportFile.write(new_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use python's string split method, splitting on the '#' character. This will return a list split on the character. You want the first item in the list as this is before the '#', so slice the list with [0] to get this. In code you would change the line in your loop to:

```
new_line = line.split('#')[0]
```

NB if you get characters other than '#' you'll need to modify the approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @MananPyJava said, you can use regular expressions.

```py
>>> s = '''\
...    1.jpg#0     One
...    2.jpg#1     Two
...    3.jpg#2     Three
...    4.jpg#3     Four
...    5.jpg#4     Five
... '''
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile(r'(#\d+)')
>>> def repl(mo):
...     return ' '*len(mo.group(1))
...
>>> print(patt.sub(repl, s))
   1.jpg       One
   2.jpg       Two
   3.jpg       Three
   4.jpg       Four
   5.jpg       Five
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate and then use string concatenation for replacing

```
for i,j in enumerate(inputFile):
    new_line = j.replace("#"+str(i), '  ')
    exportFile.write(new_line)
```